# Datatable -Row Filter using Windcard in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview

I have datatable which has data as below now i need to fileter the rows based on column Role which contains the value 5:4 but when i filter through dataview rowfilter i am getting rows with values 75:4 also which is wrong below is the code i have tried , could anyone help me filter the particular value using dataview

[image]

datatabl;e looks like above

and below is c# code that i tried to filter

```
DataView dv1 = new DataView(dt);
                dv1.RowFilter = "Role like'%5:4%'";
                dt1 = dv1.ToTable();
```

Comment: did you at least try any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `RowFilter` which is very limited and outdated but Linq-To-DataTable:

```
var matchingRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   let roles = row.Field<string>("Role").Split('/')
                   where roles.Contains("5:4") 
                   select row;
```

This approach first splits the string by `/` and then searches in this array with `Contains`.

If you need to know if there was a matching row:

```
bool hasMatchingRows = matchingRows.Any();
```

if you want to create a new DataTable with those mathing rows:

```
if( hasMatchingRows )
{
    DataTable tblMatches = matchingRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

If you just want to know the initial-column of the matching.rows:

```
List<string> initials = matchingRows.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Initial")).ToList();
```

which contains only `NML` and `GGRA` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
dv1.RowFilter = "Role like'%5:4%'";
```

with

```
dv1.RowFilter = "Role like '5:4/%' OR Role like '%/5:4' OR Role = '5:4' OR Role like '%/5:4/%'";
//                             ^                   ^                ^                    ^
//                        startswith            endswith         equals              contains
```